# Is there really a southwards 1 N force on me due to my latitude?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, estimation, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I live in the UK at approx. $53 ^\circ$ latitude.

The horizontal component of my centripetal acceleration due to the Earths spin works out at $1.3$ N.

That's like the weight of an apple.

Is that right?

I mean it's more than I would have thought.

Surely that is significant enough that say builders and athletes etc must take it into account.

Imagine a gymnast who honed their balancing beam skills in the UK going to a country near the equator only to find that their balance is just a little off.

Comment: I think they determine the effective vertical using the plumb bob. I'm not sure if that's how they do it but that'd be one way to do it.

Comment: @DvijD.C. - That is exactly how local vertical is defined.

Comment: @DvijD.C.Interesting, that's the first times I've considered a ''local' vertical.

Comment: A Newton really isn’t very large. Neither is a Joule (Newton-meter). Consider that one Krispy Kreme donut has 800000 Joules in it, equivalent to applying one Newton over 800 kilometers.

Answer (score 0):

That 1.3 N divided by you weight would give an approximation to the angle (in radians)  between the local vertical and the direction to the center of the earth.  A plumb would swing slightly to the South so that the tension in the string could provide that northward component of acceleration. That angle would also be affected by the extra mass of earth around the equator.

Comment: Re, "A plumb would swing slightly to the South." It would if the Earth was a perfect sphere. In fact, its shape is somewhat squashed (a.k.a., "[oblate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid)"), and its surface, on average, is level everywhere.

Comment: Non-spherical is why I mentioned the extra mass at the equator.  “Level” is pretty much defined as perpendicular to a plumb line.  In fact the surface goes “down hill”  from the equator to the pole.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your meaning when you said, "A plumb line would swing slightly to the south." Certainly, it would swing slightly to the South of the imaginary line connecting the hook from which the plumb bob depends to the geometric center of the Earth. But from the viewpoint of somebody standing _on_ the Earth, near the plumb line, and unable to see the shape of the whole Earth, that deviation might not be apparent.

Comment: Right, I should have been more specific. It swings south from a line going to the center of the Earth.